# Filter Data in Workbook2 based on the cell value in cell values in Workbook1

Tags: excel, vba

I need a VBA code that will filter the data in Workbook2 based on the cell value in Workbook1.

For Example:
I need to pick up data from the cell under Filtered Data

[image]

Split the data if there are multiple values separated by semicolon and apply filter using xlOr operation in Workbook1. The data which needs to be filtered will be dynamic based on the cell value.

[image]

Comment: Why don´t you use the autofilter in VBA?

Comment: @clomee i am using Autofilter. 
For the first cell value code should be: Activesheet.Range("A1"). AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="A", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="B", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria:="C"


I need to keep Criteria Field Dynamic

Comment: Should it just show values which contain a, b or c or all together or just show them if they are the same?

Comment: Yes it should filter the values which contains a,b,orc

Comment: Does it work now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution you are looking for is a simple Split function.

```
criterias = Split(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 1).Value, ";")
```

It splits the string in sheet 1 cell A2 into an array, it cuts at ";" and will just be an array. In thi case the Array will look like criterias=[A,B,C]
When you got that string you can use autofilter.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=criterias, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

That will filter it so that it shows just all cells which contain A, B or C.
You can change Thisworkbook.worksheets(1) to whatever the second workbook is.